# Why can I not see users in my Firebase Authentication console?

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am extremely new to dev work. I wanted to play around and try using Firebase Auth in my xcode project. I followed all of the steps to create a simple sign in view with email and password using Firebase and everything works great. When I run the app in the simulation, I can see that it is printing 'success' when I input a new email and password. Unfortunately, when I check the Firebase console to see if that email shows up, the console shows empty.

I even tried running the simulation again with a different password and it prints:

> Error: Error domain..... Code=17007 "The email address is already in use by another account.

This  tells me that its successfully creating the account, but I'm just not seeing it on the Firebase console.

Again, super super new to all of this, but any ideas on what I could be doing wrong/what went wrong?

I tried deleting the app in Firebase and connecting a new one and its still doing it.

Comment: Without seeing exactly what you're seeing (console, code, and how you're working with them), it's not really possible for us to understand what you might be doing wrong. Stack Overflow is only useful when you provide [minimal complete steps to reproduce](https://overflow.tips/write-good-question/minimal-complete-reproducible-example) some unexpected behavior. If you think there is a problem with the Firebase console, you should explain that to [Firebase support](https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support) directly.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback for my first post. Moving forward I will do better providing that content. FWIW - I didn't realize when I reset the app in Firebase, I needed to switch the app at the top. 

Note to self: if you reset your app and use the same name, it can be confusing.